# Convert Image to SVG

Tags: java, canvas, svg, batik

I use [Apache Batik](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) to preview svg documents in a jframe.
What I want to do is the user to give some Images (e.g. png or jpeg)
and then my program to turn them into svg documents.

Is this `SVGCreator` any possible?

> FileChooser

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(".");
  int choice = fc.showOpenDialog(panel);
  if(choice == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
    File f = fc.getSelectedFile();
    String filepath = f.toURL().toString();
    SVGDocument document = SVGCreator(filepath);
    SVGViewer(document);
  }
}
```

> SVGViewer (extends JFrame)

```
public SVGViewer(SVGDocument document){
  JSVCanvas canvas = new JSVCanvas();
  this.getContentPane().add(canvas);
  canvas.setSVGDocument(document);
  this.pack();
  this.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: the thing is that even if I open a png with Illustrator or Photoshop and export it as an .svg, the SVGViewer does not display this svg....  It works with some sample svg files provided with Apache Batik. Maybe batik uses a custom format for svg files

Comment: png and jpeg are raster formats, SVG is a vector format. Batik does not use a custom format for SVG files, although it is very strict about what it accepts.

Comment: so is there any way to do what I want or not?

Comment: **In a practical sense...No**, you cannot auto-magically convert jpg/png (raster) to SVG (vector). Adobe Illustrator has a whole roomful of developers and their raster->vector converter (IMHO) is only "OK, but not great". No slam against Adobe -- it's just ### hard to do!